# Unable to loop JSON array

Tags: jquery, json

When I am reading the JSON Array, it is coming as String.
I'm unable to loop JSON array.

JSON Array is coming as string

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 
 
 
 var jsonReponse = {
    "peopledata": {
        "london": {
            "name": "Mike",
            "age": "15"
        }

    },
    "allData": {
        "london": [{
            "name": "Mike",
            "city": "London",
            "age": 15,
            "dateOfBirth": "01/01/1981"
        }, {
            "name": "Pavan",
            "city": "London",
            "age": 1,
            "dateOfBirth": "01/01/1981"
        }]
    }
}

var selectedCity = 'london';

var jsonResp = getAllDetailsArray(selectedCity);


alert(jsonResp.length)




function getAllDetailsArray(selectedCity) {
    return JSON.stringify(jsonReponse.allData[selectedCity]);
}
 
 
});
```

my sample fiddle
read json coming as String
https://jsfiddle.net/vn9aL32k/1/

Comment: I don't understand the question, what output do you expect?

Comment: You just need to remove `JSON.stringify`.

Comment: It's string because you converted it to string. Don't convert it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the `JSON.stringify` will fix this

```
function getAllDetailsArray(selectedCity) {
    return jsonReponse.allData[selectedCity];
}
```

[Check this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v0ex9Lhd/)